# Get closest time from data

Tags: python, json

Below is the sample data:

```
{
   "a":"05:32",
   "b":"12:15",
   "c":"15:42",
   "d":"18:23"
}
```

Using this data: I want to get the closest next value to the current time.
ie; So if it is, 15:30 right now, the query should return c.

I tried to do this with a for loop and it didn't seem very efficient.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `min` with a custom key function:

```
d = {'a': '05:32', 'b': '12:15', 'c': '15:42', 'd': '18:23'}
def closest(c, t2 = [15, 30]):
   a, b = map(int, d[c].split(':'))
   return abs((t2[-1]+60*t2[0]) - (b+60*a))       

new_d = min(d, key=closest)
```

Output:

```
c
```

In general, you can replace `t2 = [15, 30]` (used only for demo purposes) with results from `datetime.datetime.now`:

```
from datetime import datetime
def closest(c, t2 = [(n:=datetime.now()).hour, n.minute]):
    ...
```